# Does Windows Server Backup copy user documents too?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, folder-redirection, windows-server-backup

I have a AD domain and have redirected the Documents folder for each of my users.  I have the "Grant the user exclusive rights to the Documents" checkbox ticked so I can't get in to see their documents.

I also have Windows Server Backup running a complete backup to a network share every night. I run the backup as a user that's part of the Backup Operators security group. I tried doing a Files and Folders Recovery and went in to look for a single file in one of my user's Documents folders and nothing showed up.

What I'm wondering: does Windows Server Backup backup the files that are in the Documents folders that users have exclusive rights to?  If my DC dies, and I do a full recovery, will all of their files still be there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works!

When I was looking in the restore section of Windows Server Backup, it didn't show the documents.  But, I did a little test-recovery of my own files and the folder with my documents showed up with all of the documents inside.

The user that is doing the backups has to be a part of the backup operators group.  That group can evidently backup documents that it doesn't have access too.

Hope this helps someone in the future :)

Comment: Yes, it was a great help, thanks. I was very concerned that I couldn't see any folders/files from within the Restore window and your suggestion for a test restore introduced my palm and my forehead to each other yet again. You'd think they'd know each other by now. +1

Comment: p.s. Where are you finding that 'Exclusive Rights' checkbox?

Comment: It's in the group policy when you're setting up folder redirection, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/288991

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be No and No for both of your questions. With the option you've set on the redirected folders, only the user and local system have access to the folders.